# Error while loading route: TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: ruby, ember.js, local-storage, ubuntu-12.04, ember-data

I truly hope someone from emberjs team will read this.

I am a pretty much experienced programmer in several languages.

& AFA ember is concerned, its not the learning curve nor do I find a lack on knowledge & tutorials,
Rather I think its the constant change in sources of the frameworks & dev environment that consume a lot of time, efforts and energy,
Trying to figure out what is going wrong when various SO questions and googles refer to different/ older versions of the framework.

I find a need for some kind of a configuration chart of what works with what and how to configure your dev environment a necessity here.

There are a lot of answers that do not necessarily point in the right direction, its hard to describe but I kind of get the feeling documentation is lagging behind while the framework is running forward.

I went through all of [José Mota](http://courses.tutsplus.com/courses/lets-learn-ember)'s great tutorial and on the last stage of building the actual bookmarks app, I ran into so many problems that learning emberjs was not the main issue but rather the infrastructure around it that consumed most of the time.

It started with ruby versions and managing these on ubuntu 12.04, [ember-data](https://github.com/emberjs/data) dependencies of ruby (compiles only with ruby 1.9), to [localstorage_adapter.js](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter) and how to work with it in ember...
The example given on github's page for the later does not work.

**Config:**
ubuntu 12.04.4
ember 1.4.1+pre.af87bd20
jquery-1.9.1
handlebars-v1.3.0
ember-data 1.0.0-beta.7.f87cba88
ruby 1.9.2p290

Following [José Mota's great tutsplus course](http://courses.tutsplus.com/courses/lets-learn-ember/lessons/lets-build-an-ember-app-part-1)
So here is my problem:

```
Error while loading route: TypeError: undefined is not a function
at App.BookmarksNewRoute.Ember.Route.extend.model (http://localhost:8000/js/app/routes/bookmarks_new.js:3:23)
at superWrapper [as model] (http://localhost:8000/js/vendor/ember.js:1239:16)
```

App Code (I will try to be clear):

**routes**

filename: bookmarks_new.js

```
App.BookmarksNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function() {
    return App.Bookmark.createRecord();
}
```

})

**models**

filename: bookmark.js

```
App.Bookmark = DS.Model.extend({
title: DS.attr("string"),
url: DS.attr("string")
```

})

**filename: router.js**

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource("bookmarks", function(){
    this.route("new");
    });
});
```

filename: store.js

```
(1)
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
revision: 14,
adapter: DS.LSAdapter
});
(2)
App.Store = DS.Store.extend();
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.LSAdapter;
(3)
App.Store = DS.Store.extend();
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.LSAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'bookmarks'
});
(4)
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.LSSerializer.extend();
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.LSAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'bookmarks'
});
```

number 1 & 4 work but which one is the right one??
numbers 2,3 where found on either SO or google different answers as resolving the matter for different people.

**Controllers**

filename: bookmarks.js

```
App.BookmarksController = Ember.ArrayController.extend();
```

filename: bookmarks_new.js

```
App.BookmarksNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
save: function() {
    this.get("model.transaction").commit();
    // this.get("model").get("transaction").commit(); // similiar
    this.get("router").transitionTo("bookmars");
}
});
```

**index.html**

** here is apperas (also by finding out another person's question) that the order in which the scripts are put in the inbdex.html is crucial:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/ember.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/ember-states.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/ember-data.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app/router.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/localstorage_adapter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app/store.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app/controllers/bookmarks.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app/controllers/bookmarks_new.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app/models/bookmark.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app/routes/bookmarks_new.js"></script>
```

**and finally the markup**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="bookmarks">
    <h2>All my Bookmarks</h2>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>URL</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            {{#each controller}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{title}}</td>
                <td>{{url}}</td>
            </tr>
            {{else}}
            <tr>
                <td>U have No bookmarks</td>
            </tr>
            {{/each}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    {{#link-to "bookmarks.new"}}Add new bookmark{{/link-to}}
    {{outlet}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="bookmarks/new">
    <h3>New Bookmark</h3>
    <form {{action "save" on="submit"}}>
        <p>
            {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="title" placeholder="type in a title"}}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="url" placeholder="type in a URL"}}
        </p>
        <p>
            <button>Create Bookmark</button>
        </p>
    </form>
</script>
```

**OK**, so clicking on 'Add new bookmark' yields the above error.

Why??

Thank you for your time...embereres...

If you find any information missing please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I encounter these problems:

```
Error while loading route: TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

It usually means that the either:

- Your model function of one of your routes return nothing (missing return statement)
- you are asking for a model that does not exist
- your XHR fails along the way, so that the model() function returns undefined

Check your network tab in the browser developer tools, to verify that you are getting the data you expect in return. In case of the local storage adapter, you need to check that you get what you expect back from it.

Edit: Maybe this screencast, which I recorded at a conference presentation I did earlier this year, might help as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KH5RreHtaaQ

Comment: Joachim thank you for your reply...gave your video a shoot but the github code is missing some files so could not really follow on your tutorial...do you have any advise where to start?? something simple/ basic as how to create the model/view/controller for a single page in an ember app...???_thank you

Comment: Have a look at the free sample chapter from my book (Ember.js in Action) here: http://manning.com/skeie/ It goes through and explains each step along the way